# Football Manager 2020 - how to automate substitutions?

Tags: football-manager-2020

How do you automate substitutions when you select instant result? i.e. when you simulate matches is there a way to ask your assistant manager, or someone else, to automatically select pertinent substitutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer myself so here it is if anyone stumbles on the same issue. When you click on 'Instant Result' you need to select 'Do not use Match Plan'. This allows your assistant manager to automate the subs for you.